# Geronimo-3.0.1 Aries Blueprint java.lang.VerifyError

Tags: geronimo, blueprint-osgi, aries

Am trying out OSGI with Aries/Blueprint using Gernomino 3.0.1. Have hit a wall because of the following exception:

```
2013-08-06 10:54:54,832 ERROR [BlueprintContainerImpl] Unable to start blueprint container for bundle com.xxx.xxx
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to instantiate components
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:644)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:331)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:206)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/xxx.xxx/services/impl/$UserServiceImpl307032798, method:  signature: (Ljava/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler;)V) Call to wrong initialization method
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2398)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2708)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1659)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.gen.ProxySubclassGenerator.newProxySubclassInstance(ProxySubclassGenerator.java:159)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.AsmProxyManager.createNewProxy(AsmProxyManager.java:81)
    at org.apache.aries.proxy.impl.AbstractProxyManager.createProxy(AbstractProxyManager.java:50)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.addInterceptors(BeanRecipe.java:688)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:728)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:64)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:219)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createAll(BlueprintRepository.java:147)
    at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.instantiateEagerComponents(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:640)
    ... 10 more
```

My JDK version is 1.7.0_25-b15 on Ubuntu 13.04.

Here's how my Blueprint configuration looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint
    xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:jpa="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/jpa/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:tx="http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.0.0">

<!-- DataSource Derby -->
<bean id="dataSourceDerby" class="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource">
    <property name="databaseName" value="/home/imme/Data/xxxxdb"/>
    <property name="createDatabase" value="create"/>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSourceXADerby" class="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedXADataSource">
    <property name="databaseName" value="/home/imme/Data/xxxxdb"/>
    <property name="createDatabase" value="create"/>
</bean>

<!-- Expose DataSource as JNDI reference -->
<service ref="dataSourceDerby" interface="javax.sql.DataSource">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/xxxxdb"/>
    </service-properties>
</service>
<service ref="dataSourceXADerby" interface="javax.sql.XADataSource">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/xaxxxxdb"/>
    </service-properties>
</service>

<bean id="userServiceImpl" class="com.xxx.xxx.services.impl.UserServiceImpl">
    <tx:transaction method="*" value="Required" />
    <jpa:context property="entityManager" unitname="xxx-unit"/>
</bean>
<service id="userService" ref="userServiceImpl" interface="com.xxx.xxxx.services.UserService"/>
</blueprint>
```

If I comment out the line:
`<tx:transaction method="*" value="Required" />`
I do not see the exception anymore, however the services don't work because the container is not able to open a transaction. Have tried with JDK 1.6, same problem.

Appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error has been fixed in latest version of areis.jpa.container but geronimo is still holding on to the old bundle.

Description of error [[http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/aries-user/201210.mbox/%3CCAJ0TPGK12vVNFyb5TXH-dxLn29aORu_y1MKR2omD_Dmi-8tMOw@mail.gmail.com%3E][1]](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/aries-user/201210.mbox/%3CCAJ0TPGK12vVNFyb5TXH-dxLn29aORu_y1MKR2omD_Dmi-8tMOw@mail.gmail.com%3E%5d%5b1%5d)

Bundles affected:
aries.jpa.container
org.apache.aries.proxy.impl
org.apache.aries.proxy